# Can Somebody explain me this snippet from code that says "start + start % 2"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code block is to determine and print even numbers

```
     def print_even_numbers(start, stop):
        for i in range(start + start % 2, stop, 2):
            print(i)
```

This `start + start % 2` was used instead of if statement. What does it do?

Comment: What exactly is not clear? What did you try to do to understand it yourself and what were your findings? Simply asking explain this code for me is not on-topic here. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask]

Answer (score 1):

It is used to start the range at the "next even number" from `start`.

Consider the basic case (without `+ start % 2`): a range from `start` to `stop` with a step 2. This would print all the even numbers in the range, provided that `start` is an even number itself (otherwise it would print all the odd numbers).

The `+ start % 2` adds the rest of the division by 2 to `start`, i.e. either 0 (when `start` is even) or 1 (when `start` is odd), to make sure the range starts indeed from the next even number.

So it's just a more compact form for:

```
def print_even_numbers(start, stop):
    # add 1 if start is odd
    if start % 2 == 1:
        start = start + 1
    for i in range(start, stop, 2):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Given the name of the function, you'd think that if `start` was even, it should also be printed

Comment: @OneCricketeer it does.

Comment: No, `start` input param isn't printed, only the next even number

Comment: @OneCricketeer it does ;) Try it.

Comment: Doh :( thought its always adding something

Answer (score 0):

`start + start % 2` gives you the first even number that is greater or equal to `start`.
The `%` is the modulo operator. For instance, `a % b` returns the remainder of dividing `a/b`.

So if start is even, `start % 2 = 0`, because `start` is divisible by `2` (as it's even). So `start + start % 2` would equal just `start`.

If start was odd, `start % 2` would be 1, therefore `start + start % 2` would equal `start + 1`.  An uneven number plus 1 always makes an even number.

Thus, the range always begins at an even number, namely the one that is closest to `start`, and gets incremented by 2, until the `stop` is reached. The result is all even numbers between `start` and `stop`.